# How come git pull working even if fetch gives an error?

Tags: git, fetch, pull

I want to retrieve latest changes from my master branch, but when when i fetch it it displays an error that some reference is broken to a sub branch. But when i directly use git pull command it worked fine and i have latest changes. But how? can  anyone please expalin. (it again shows same error while git fetch)

Comment: please show us the error you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well `git fetch` will attempt to update *all* your local tracking branches, while doing just a `git pull` on your current branch will only update that particular branch.

Your next step to fix this is to diagnose and figure out what is the branch causing the error in `git fetch`.  If you can't pull that branch, then you might want to check your remote repository (e.g. GitHub, Bitbucket) to see what recent activity might be responsible for this.